# Hiding text in title (Wordpress)

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I'm using Wordpress and would like to hide the word 'Protected' that is with the title 'Protected: Pavanjot & Amandeep’s Wedding' I'd like the rest of the title to remain as is.

I'm guessing using custom css I can target the below code to hide the word? I'm unsure on how to achieve this though.

```
<header class="entry-header page-header">
        <h1 class="entry-title">Protected: Pavanjot &amp; Amandeep’s Wedding</h1>
    </header>
```

I'd like to hide the word, or remove it, so the remaining text aligns left and does not leave a gap.

Any help is great thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If this is your post title, then place this function in your functions.php, your issue will be solved.

```
function change_title($title) {
    if (strpos($title, 'Protected:') !== false) {
        $title = str_replace("Protected:","",$title);

    }
    return $title;
}
add_filter('the_title', 'change_title');
```

Hope, this may be useful for you.

Comment: try this, i think it would work for page title also.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can do that with CSS without modifying the markup (and then you could just remove the text), but you can do it with a couple of lines of JS.

```html
<h1 class="entry-title">Protected: Pavanjot &amp; Amandeep’s Wedding</h1>
<script>
var entryTitle = document.querySelector('.entry-title'),
  text = entryTitle.innerHTML;
entryTitle.innerHTML = text.substring(text.indexOf(" "), text.length);
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks, and I guess I'd just add the js to a custom plugin like I use for custom css?

Comment: @Dano007 I can't say since I don't know how your site is structured. But you can just add it in a script tag under the `h1`. Updated my answer to reflect that.